# How to get HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse in SOAP interceptor in spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, soap, spring-security

I have a spring boot application with SOAP endpoints and an interceptor class which implements `EndpointInterceptor`.The problem is, there is no overridden methods available in this interface which have access to `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`.

My question is :

1. How can I get `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects whenever an API request comes using a SOAP interceptor (I saw many examples which is using `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and `HandlerInterceptor` but it is working only for Rest @Controller. In my case it is SOAP with @Endpoint and it is not calling the overridden methods).
2. If that is not possible , how can i get make this object from `MessageContext` since the handleRequest overridden method is having that parameter as show below

   @Override
   public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext,
   Object endpoint) throws Exception {
   LOG.info("Endpoint Request Handling");
   return true;
   }

Comment: SOAP doesn't care about transports hence you cannot access this directly. Why do you need to access the request/response directly? What additional information you need that you cannot get through the normal support?

Answer (score 3):

Spring-ws has TransportContext class for storing the current underlying connection. You can access it via TransportContextHolder class statically in the code.

If you are sure that the underlying connection is a HttpServletConnection then you could do something like this inside the interceptor methods:

```
TransportContext ctx = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
HttpServletRequest req = ((HttpServletConnection) ctx.getConnection()).getHttpServletRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate (Override) the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse
before/after reaching the endpoints using Interceptors would be a bad idea as the requests reached at that level would be preprocessed and would not give you the option of modification.

You could use **Filters** instead of Interceptors to achieve what your trying to do.

Comment: I am not manipulating (modifying) the HttpServlet object. I just need some of the information from that object to process a business logic.

Comment: what are the information you require. Adding more code snippets would be helpful.